# Problem with Select Menu using pycord, discord.py and discord.ui. Unknown interaction

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I'm making a bot that scrolls through an interaction in the select menu, and sometimes the code breaks and shows a error in the terminal.

But it is very strange, because I have seen three things happen:

1. The bot adds the selected position but it appears in the discord: "This interaction failed" and the error appears in the terminal.
2. The bot does not give the job and "This interaction failed" appears along with the error in the terminal
3. It works perfectly, without any erors.

My code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import View, Select

intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def select(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(title="", 
  description="Choose your color:\n - Red\n - Green\n - Blue", 
  color=discord.Color.orange())

  async def select_callback(interaction):
      user = interaction.user

      r = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Vermelho")
      g = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Verde")
      b = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Azul")
      await user.remove_roles(r, g, b)

      role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=str(select.values[0]))
      await user.add_roles(role)

      await interaction.response.defer()

  select = Select(
  min_values=1,
  max_values=1,
  placeholder="Choose your color here",
  options={discord.SelectOption(emoji="", label="Vermelho", description="Color red"),
          discord.SelectOption(emoji="", label="Verde", description="Color green"),
          discord.SelectOption(emoji="", label="Azul", description="Color blue"),}
  )

  select.callback = select_callback

  view = View(timeout=None)
  view.add_item(select)

  await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)

  
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Running")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

The error:

```py
ERROR    discord.ui.view Ignoring exception in view <View timeout=None children=1> for item <Select placeholder='Choose your color here' min_values=1 max_values=1 disabled=False options={<SelectOption label='Verde' value='Verde' description='Color green' emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='' id=No ne> default=False>, <SelectOption label='Azul' value='Azul' description='Color blue' emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name=
'' id=None> default=False>, <SelectOption label='Vermelho' value='Vermelho' description='Color red' emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='' id=None> default=False>}>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\Programação\Projetos\Python\Bots\Cosk Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 425, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "c:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\Programação\Projetos\Python\Bots\Cosk Bot\aaaa.py", line 28, in select_callback
    await interaction.response.defer()
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\Programação\Projetos\Python\Bots\Cosk Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\interactions.py", line 636, in defer
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\Programação\Projetos\Python\Bots\Cosk Bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\webhook\async_.py", line 218, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is happening because you're trying to defer the interaction at the very end of the callback. A fix for this would be to add the defer at the very top of the of the callback like this

```
async def select_callback(interaction):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    ...
```

Also another thing I noticed is that you're not sending any response back to the user after deferring. This will raise the `Interaction Failed` error on Discord's side after 15 minutes, because you're sending anything. I suggest you send at least a confirmation message to the user after you're finished with the code.